# Error on No Operating Systems Detected

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside with windows 8.1 .

I have four partitions on the disk. The fourth one is empty with space 71 GB. I'm hoping to install Ubuntu here.

But when I'm trying to install, I'm getting the error `No operating systems found`.

I tried using fixparts but it doesn't work. It shows the following error:

```
This disk appears to be a GPT disk. Use GNU Parted or GPT fdisk on it!
Exiting!
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: On which step of the installation did the error appears exactly (No operation system found)?

Answer (score -1):

According to me u want to download ubuntu along side windows on the same disk on which u installed windows.

---

If you want to install ubuntu in separate disk then choose the last option (The Last option is "Something else")

---

After choosing this you should choose the Drive in which you want to install the ubuntu and make three parts of that

---

1.First alot memory of about 15-20gb(My personal recommendation you can choose less also but it should not be less than 10 gb.Mount it as /

---

2.Now give this about 10 gb of space and mount it as Swap area.

---

3.Give the left over memory to second partition and mount it as /home .

---

After this just simply install ubuntu.

---

After installing ubuntu you will notice that after rebooting it u will either be directed to Ubuntu or windows (You will not be asked your choice).

---

If you boot into ubuntu directly then just run a command in Terminal

---

sudo update-grub

---

If you directly boot into windows then use BOOTREPAIR.After running this your problem will be solved.

---

BootRepair can also be used if you directly boot into Ubuntu